# Stream changes in available memory

Tags: linux, bash, memory, monitoring, io

I've come up with the following command to check changes in memory use:

```
free -s 1 -h | awk 'NR%4==2'
```

This shows output like this:

```
Mem:           125G         32G         82G        404M         10G         91G     
Mem:           125G         32G         82G        404M         10G         91G     
Mem:           125G         32G         82G        404M         10G         92G
```

I'm actually only interested in changes of memory use, so I tried piping this through `uniq`:

```
free -s 1 -h | awk 'NR%4==2' | uniq
```

However, when using this, no output is given at all. I assume `uniq` is waiting for its input to finish but of course it never does.

I'm on RedHat 7.6

Comment: Yes, `uniq` is waiting, I think not for the end of the file but for just one more line (it applies only for adjacent lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example from [`man stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) is what you are looking for. It applies for the general case you want to pipe a stream to `uniq`, similar to this. And the reason is that `uniq` needs to see more lines to decide if current line should be printed or not.

```
EXAMPLES
       tail -f access.log | stdbuf -oL cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq
       This will immediately display unique entries from access.log
```

For your case:

```
free -s1 -h | stdbuf -oL awk 'NR%4==2' | uniq
```

---

Another way to do this is using one `awk` command, saving the line just printed and testing against this value before printing:

```
free -s1 -h | awk 'NR%4 == 2 {if ($0 != p) print; p = $0}'
```

---

Also, to monitor the output of a command, `watch` could be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot. I made a small tweak `free -s1 -h | awk 'NR%4==2 {if ($0!=p) {print strftime("%H:%M:%S"), $0}; p = $0}'` This wasn't in my question but also gives me a timestamp for each line which is useful. I tried to do `"date" | getline date` as well but that gives the time at the start of the command.

Comment: Nice. It is better to use GNU awk date functions, than external calls. If you had to use external call, it would be like this, to get renewed date: `{if ($0 != p) {cmd = "date +%T"; cmd | getline var; close(cmd); print var,p}; p = $0}'`.